# Siddhi HTTP NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, wso2, siddhi

This question is about java library of Siddhi - CEP

**Description:**

I tried to establish an HTTP source to receive data. There was no error creating the Runtime and starting it.

```
[nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] INFO org.wso2.transport.http.netty.listener.ServerConnectorBootstrap$HTTPServerConnector - HTTP(S) Interface starting on host localhost and port 9056
[main] INFO org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.http.source.HttpConnectorPortBindingListener - siddhi: started HTTP server connector localhost:9056
[main] INFO org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.http.source.HttpSourceListener - Source Listener has created for url http://localhost:9056/endpoints/
```

However, when I send a POST request to the designated address. I get an error:

```
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] ERROR org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.http.source.HTTPConnectorListener - Error in http server connector
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest.method()Lio/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpMethod;
    at org.wso2.transport.http.netty.listener.CustomHttpContentCompressor.decode(CustomHttpContentCompressor.java:44)
    at org.wso2.transport.http.netty.listener.CustomHttpContentCompressor.decode(CustomHttpContentCompressor.java:14)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec$2.decode(MessageToMessageCodec.java:81)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:354)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Could anyone suggest a reason of what I have done wrong? Thank you in advance.

**Affected Product Version:**
4.1.17

**OS, DB, other environment details and versions:**
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.5 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-173.4674.33, built on March 6, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b15 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

**Steps to reproduce:**
The test code I wrote:

```
import org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiAppRuntime;
import org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager;
import org.wso2.siddhi.core.event.Event;
import org.wso2.siddhi.core.stream.output.StreamCallback;
import org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.EventPrinter;
//import org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.http.source.*;

public class httpTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String siddhiString = "@App:name(\"haha\") " +
                "@App:description(\"fasd\") " +
                "@App:statistics(reporter = \"jmx\", interval = \"30\") " +
                "@source(type=\"http\",receiver.url=\"http://localhost:9056/endpoints/\",@map(type=\"text\",fail.on.missing.attribute=\"true\",regex.A=\"(.*)\",@attributes(data=\"A\"))) " +
                "@sink(type=\"mqtt\",url=\"tcp://120.78.71.179:1883\",topic=\"34\",@map(type=\"text\")) " +
                "define stream a4P068X5YCK(data String);";
        SiddhiManager siddhiManager = new SiddhiManager();
        SiddhiAppRuntime siddhiAppRuntime = siddhiManager.createSiddhiAppRuntime(siddhiString);

        siddhiAppRuntime.addCallback("a4P068X5YCK", new StreamCallback() {
            @Override
            public void receive(Event[] events) {
                EventPrinter.print(events);
            }
        });

        siddhiAppRuntime.start();
    }
}
```

Then I send a POST request to http://localhost:9056/endpoints/. It returns the exception posted above.

**Update:**
I went back and check the [Siddhi-io-http github documentation page](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-http/). I found that it says:

> ... This extension only works inside the WSO2 Data Analytic Server and cannot be run with standalone siddhi.

I guess it might suggest that http is not supported by siddhi library at the moment. I have submitted issue on siddhi repository page to ask for confirmation.

**Update 2:**
I have changed my Siddhi Query so that it copy the source stream into the other sink stream. Other part of the code remains the same:

```
String siddhiString = "@App:name(\"haha\") " +
            "@App:description(\"fasd\") " +
            "@App:statistics(reporter = \"jmx\", interval = \"30\") " +
            "@source(type=\"http\",receiver.url=\"http://localhost:9056/endpoints/\",@map(type=\"text\",fail.on.missing.attribute=\"true\",regex.A=\"(.*)\",@attributes(data=\"A\"))) " +
            "define stream a4P068X5YCK(data String); " +
            "@sink(type=\"mqtt\",url=\"tcp://120.78.71.179:1883\",topic=\"34\",@map(type=\"text\")) " +
            "define stream pout(data String); " +
            "from a4P068X5YCK " +
            "select * " +
            "insert into pout; " +
            "";
```

The same problem still exists. I tried the wso2 processor and it works fine. Now my guesses are:
1. version mismatch
2. lack of some packages in wso2 processor dependecies.

I will try to identify it in those two direction and will update in here and Issue page as soon as I find something new.

**Update 3:**
As I keep adding updates, the format seems to have some problem but fortunately this issue also comes to an end. I tried to Include all dependencies from wso2 processor source code and my test program starts working. Therefore I assume there is a component in wso2 processor that siddhi library is lacking.

I tried to delete the dependencies one by one to see if my test program still works. Finally I have found that package. With this package my code works well.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.msf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.wso2.msf4j.feature</artifactId>
        <version>${msf4j.version}</version>
            <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
```

As I am a beginner to coding, I am not exactly what was the problem. I would be grateful if someone could explain to me the reason behind the problem. I appreciate all the helps received in this process and it would also be a great experience for me.

**Update 4:** @Grainier I tried the sample code you posted and it actually worked! Although I still have no idea why. I tried to copy your exact code to a new .java in my project. It still won't work. Therefore I guess there is something to do with POM file.

Something I noticed is that when I ran your sample code there are few more WARNINGS printed in console: **SMALL UPDATE: I have found that the Warnings appeared because I am using JDK 10. As soon as I switch back to 1.8 warnings disappeared and the code still works. So maybe this is not the reason.**

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/C:/Users/ktz001/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.16.Final/netty-common-4.1.16.Final.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

The second difference is in the POM file. In  you have one more repository added compared to mine.

```
<repository>
        <id>wso2-nexus</id>
        <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
```

It would be great if you could suggest any reason.
Thank you for all of your work! It has been really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the documentation... This should work with standalone Siddhi. All you have to do is add following dependencies in your project (also mqtt, which I haven't included below);

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.siddhi</groupId>
        <artifactId>siddhi-core</artifactId>
        <version>${siddhi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.siddhi</groupId>
        <artifactId>siddhi-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${siddhi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.siddhi</groupId>
        <artifactId>siddhi-query-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${siddhi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.http</groupId>
        <artifactId>siddhi-io-http</artifactId>
        <version>${siddhi.io.http.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.text</groupId>
        <artifactId>siddhi-map-text</artifactId>
        <version>${siddhi.mapper.text.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However, there's an issue with your query which is, you have defined a `@source` and a `@sink` to a single stream. Which is wrong. If you want to make it a passthrough, then you have to define two streams (one for source and one for sink) and write a query to insert events from source stream to sink stream.

UPDATE:

A sample can be found [here](https://github.com/grainier/siddhi-io-http-sample); Please try that and see whether it's working.

Comment: Thank you for your reply (on both platform :D)! I tried to change the Siddhi QL but the same problem persists. FYI please see "update 2"

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working sample, can you please check. Note: It doesn't include mqtt

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your code actually works for me but now I am wondering why. If you have time please check "Update 3" where I make my own program work, and "Update 4" the difference between my sample to yours.